# Is FTP user isolation adequate security for a Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows, security, ftp, windows-server-2008

On my Windows 2008 web server I've also setup an FTP site with user isolation within user folders and the NTFS permissions are set so that users only have read access to their own folder.

Though I am by no means a security expert I am attempting to be security conscious so I would like to know if there are any other steps I can take to harden the FTP service against attack?  I've read that FTP is not very secure so I want to do everything I can to combat that.

The data available to the users on the FTP site is not sensitive so encryption is not a requirement.  Mainly I just want to make every effort to keep malicious users out of any other parts of the web server.

Comment: SSH might be a better alternative regarding security. Users should have no trouble using WinSCP or similar applications to access files.

Comment: Thank you DrMoishe Pippik, I will look into that alternative.

Comment: Should be reasonably secure if there aren't any `NTFS junction points` present and the users can't create them some other way. Junction points would provide a way for the users to traverse higher up the directory tree if they pointed outside of the isolation environment.

Comment: Thanks ssnobody.  I was not familiar with NTFS junction points but after looking them up it appears that I would have needed to intentionally create them, which I have not.  As far as users creating junction points, I believe they should not be able to create anything since I've only given them read permissions.